# How does xcode project for a command line tool designate which swift file is the entry point?

Tags: xcode, swift, program-entry-point

I've apparently done something wrong to my xcode (v6.3.1) project using Swift. When I attempt to build, my startup statements in Main.swift are flagged with a compiler error: "Statements are not allowed at the top level". This project contains multiple targets, each building multiple Swift files. Just my command-line app target is failing to build this way.

Is there a setting somewhere in the project file that designates which Swift file is the main entry point, and thus allows top-level statements?

Comment: Looks like it's case sensitive. main.swift works, but Main.swift does not. Still would like to know if there's a project setting or source-level option I can use to control this.